# Delete elements from observable array list

Tags: javascript

i was hoping if you could help me with a small javascript program, my program seems working fine when i add elements(customer and their type) to the array, but i am not sure how to add button next to the observable array elements so the user can delete their desired entries one by one? figure below shows what i want the program to look like:! many thanks!

```js
 

function addCustomer() 
{         
    var newIndex = customerList.length;
    customerList[newIndex] = new Object;
    customerList[newIndex].name = document.getElementById('name').value.trim();
    customerList[newIndex].childOrAdult = childOrAdult.options[childOrAdult.selectedIndex].value;
    displayCustomers();
    
}

function displayCustomers() 
{    
    var message = ''; 
    

    var message = '<tr><td><b>&nbsp;CUSTOMER NAME&nbsp;</b></td><td><b>&nbsp;CHILD/ADULT&nbsp;</b></td></tr>\n';
    for (var i = 0 ; i < customerList.length ; i++) 
    {
        message += '<br><tr><td>&nbsp;' + customerList[i].name + '&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;' 
                   + String(customerList[i].childOrAdult) + '&nbsp;</br></td></tr>\n';      
    }            
   document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = message;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Giant Trampoline Customers</title>
<script src="" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body onload="displayCustomers();">
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Giant Trampoline Customers</h1>
<div id="outputDiv" style="text-align: center;"></div>
<br>
<div id="inputDiv" style="text-align: center">

<h3>Add A Customer:</h3>
 New customer's name: <input type="text" id="name" maxlength="30" value="" size="30">


</select>
<button type="button" onclick="addAndDisplayCustomer();">add</button>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

![desired result ][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/json/asdzgst9/)** (http://jsfiddle.net/json/asdzgst9/)

First, you might want to replace the `<div id="outputDiv">` with a `<table>`, if you want to display the data in a table. So,

```
<div id="outputDiv" style="text-align: center;"></div>
```

becomes:

```
<table id="outputTable" style="text-align: center;"></table>
```

Second, you need to update the function where you display all elements from the `customerList` so it renders an extra table column with a button.

```
function displayCustomers() {
    var message = '<tr><td><b>&nbsp;CUSTOMER NAME&nbsp;</b></td><td><b>&nbsp;CHILD/ADULT&nbsp;</b></td><td></td></tr>';

    for (var i = 0 ; i < customerList.length ; i++) {
        message += '<tr><td>&nbsp;' + customerList[i].name + '&nbsp;</td>';
        message += '<td>' + customerList[i].childOrAdult + '&nbsp;</td>';

        // Here, create a third column with a button.
        message += '<td><button onclick="removeCustomer(' + i + ')">remove this customer</button></td></tr>';
    }

    // Note: we have replaced the outputDiv with outputTable here!
    document.getElementById('outputTable').innerHTML = message;
}
```

Third, a function that handles a click on the new button and removes an element from the list by the provided index.

```
function removeCustomer(index) {
    // remove 1 element from the array customerList from the given index.
    customerList.splice(index, 1);

    displayCustomers();
}
```

---

**Sorting**
To sort the array, you can call [a build-in method `sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). See the updated **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/json/asdzgst9/)** (http://jsfiddle.net/json/asdzgst9/).
Update the function `displayCustomers` and add the the following snippet before the `for` loop:

```
    customerList.sort(function (customerA, customerB) {
        if (customerA.name < customerB.name) {
            return -1;
        } else if (customerA.name > customerB.name) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Ox2D9A3 :) if i have any questions i will ask you :) merry xmas

Comment: Dear Ox2D9A3, do you know how can i sort the name of the customer automatically according to alphabetical order?

Comment: @Brittany See my update. Just put this code to the right place!